# Given an array of strings and char, return strings containing char? I've gotten O(N^2), but is there a way to optimize?

Tags: python, arrays, string, runtime, big-o

Given an array of strings and char, return strings containing char (no built in functions)? I've gotten O(N^2), but is there a way to optimize? Perhaps a way utilizing a dict? Thanks! Edit: Strings are unsorted/unique to list.

```
def find_char(array, char_to_find):
    strings = []
    for i in xrange(len(array)):
        notFound = True
        for j in xrange(len(array[i])):
            if array[i][j] == char_to_find and notFound:
                strings.append(array[i])
                notFound = False
    return strings

array = ['bob', 'yo', 'hello', 'yes']
print find_char(array, 'o')
```

Comment: instead of the notFound flag, you should just break out of the inner for loop when the first condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Technically it's a list, not an array.

Comment: Do you know anything about the input strings.   I don't think you can avoid the outer for loop which loops over all of the strings.  The question is, can you reduce the complexity of checking for the character in any one string below O(n).  If the strings are sorted for example, you could do a binary search which is O(log n).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that, but no. All strings are unique and unsorted.

Answer (score 0):

```
return [hit for hit in array if char_to_find in hit]
```

Does this not qualify?

Also, how does your solution come up as O(N^2)?  I see it as O(N*M), where M is a fair statistic of the string length, and N is the length of **array**.

---

I got more info from the complexity searches:

1. The **in** operator is linear, **O(m)** (length of the string being searched).  In "good" cases, it's **O(m/t)**, where **t** is length of the string we want to find.  That's 1 in this application.
2. List comprehension is faster than **append**, but still **O(n)**.
3. We seem stuck with taking each word in the list individually: **O(n)**.

That leaves us still with **O(n^2 * m)**.

Now ... is it worth implementing a linked list of strings to get O(1) insertion (front of the list)?  It has a higher overhead, but drops the complexity to **O(n*m)**.

---

@Bi Rico, thanks.  I misread my own link (why did you post it a second time?).  **append** is, indeed, **O(n)**, so the original problem does have complexity **O(m*n)**.

Comment: Never mind, I see: the **append** operation gives the N^2 component.

Comment: I like that solution for real-world work, but in the case of an interview, I don't think that's what they would be looking for... How fast is that solution out of curiosity?

Comment: I don't know the complexity, because I'm not *certain* of the speed with which Python builds a list.  I like to think that it's properly optimized to be constant time.  I would also like to think that the **in** operator is something better than pure linear **O(M)**, but I have less confidence in that.

Comment: In my limited experience in Python-based job interviews (3, I think), they've been quite happy that I use comprehensions as a natural, idiomatic way of programming.

Comment: @Prune "in" checks are O(n) for strings/lists of length n. The amount of elements you have to look at grows linearly with n. It's impossible to bring it down to a "better" complexity class. Sure, in the average case you don't have to look at n elements, but O(n/c) = O(n) where c is any constant !=0.

Comment: Thanks; in our discussion, that would be O(M), length of the strings.  Do you happen to know whether the list comprehension is faster than *list*.append() ?  /// Never mind -- I found the [mother lode](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) with a simple search.

Comment: @Prune the list comp is faster but still in the same complexity class.

Comment: Thanks again; when I talk about complexity, I tend to use "faster" and similar terms in the *complexity* sense: two **O(N)** processes are the *same* "fastness".  I'll watch this in the future.

Comment: `append` has O(1) amortized complexity, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, you don't need to implement your own linked list.

Answer (score -1):

A few tips. Convert the string into a set and then check for membership in the set.  That becomes an O(1) operation.  I'm not sure the runtime for `in` when it comes to strings (I'd guess O(n)). Still, the time to convert the each string to a set is linear in the size of the string (as pointed out in the comments) so while this may run faster than your solution by eliminating the inner for loop, it does not guarantee and asymptotic runtime better than O(N^2)

```
def find_char(array, char_to_find):
        strings = []
        for my_string in array:
            str_chars = set(my_string)
            if char_to_find in str_chars:
                strings += [my_string]
        return strings

    array = ['bob', 'yo', 'hello', 'yes']
    print find_char(array, 'o')
```

Comment: Hint: And the complexity for conversion to set is... ? :)

Comment: Fair enough.  It's linear in the size of the string.  So it should be O (n * m) if n is the number of strings and m is the size of a string.  So I guess that's O(N^2) as well.

Comment: Well we definitely have the upper bound O(max(n,m)^2).